# Rails loop value pairs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, loops

I'm trying to create an array from another array + a count variable.

```
Array1 = [100,101,102]
count = 0
```

I want the result to be `NewArray = [ [0,100],[1,101],[2,102] ]`

I've tried so many different loops and structures but can't get it.

Example:

```
<% @daArray.each do |da| %>
      <%= "["+da.to_s+","+count.to_s+"]" %>
      <% if count != @daArray.count-1 %>
          <%= ","%>
      <% end %>
      <% count += 1 %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: So many? Could you post a couple?

Comment: we need to see an attempt to help you

Comment: updated with an example. Thanks! That gets it to the screen, but I know that it's very poorly written and can't actually be used to dump into jquery to create a graph (with a gem I'm using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
ary = [100,101,102]
upper_range = ary.size - 1  # Your "count"
new_ary = (0..upper_range).zip(ary)   # "zip" together the two
new_ary # => [[0, 100], [1, 101], [2, 102]]
```

See also [Array#zip documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-zip)

Another way of accomplishing the same result:

```
count = -1
ary.map do |el| 
  count += 1
  [count, el] 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the array in the form you want, you can use `each_with_index` which will take a block. Arguments are the value from the array and the index.

```
your_array.each_with_index.map { |value, i| [i, value] }
```

To output the array object in a JavaScript array notation, you can actually just convert it to JSON:

```
your_array.to_json
```

To take `your_array` that looks like `[100, 101, 102]` and convert it directly into a string for insertion as JavaScript, just combine the two:

```
<%= your_array.each_with_index.map { |value, i| [i, value] }.to_json %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = []
[100,101,102].each_with_index{|val, index| arr << [index, val]}
```